# How to Calculate amount value of employees repeated many times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL file that contains more than 500 employees. So many employee are repeated many times like

```
 Name    amount   Id 
 --------------------     
 Raj     500      1
 Kumar   300      4
 Karthi  400      3
 Raj     300      1
 Raj     800      1
 Kumar   300      4
```

In the above sample, `Raj` is repeated many times. My question: I want to calculate all `Raj` name `Amount` values. How can I get the total amount of `Raj` employee? Please give some idea please help me

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server? Please remove the unrelated tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `sum` and `group by`

```
select sum(amount), Name from table Group by name
```

Comment: one more Help  sir how i will get remain fields ?

Comment: `select sum(amount), Name,id from table Group by Name,id` But i do not understand your ID, because it is not a unique identifier

Comment: yes  ID is unique  its based Employee Expenses for every month. smaple Data Raj  Id is unique  he is spend some amount every month  so ID is always unique but amount will different every month sir.

Comment: @Thennarasu so it is a foreign key or something like that, not an id

Comment: sir its not foreign key  just  Employee Code sir

Comment: @Thennarasu Ah ok. Then rename the column ;)